# Where do you publish/unpublished apps on new Google Play Developer site

Tags: google-play

I can't for the life of me find the unpublish/publish switch on the new Google Play developer site. It used to be in pricing but I just cannot find it.

I currently have an app unpublished and need to change it back to published but can't find the option.

I cannot switch back to the classic version as I get a 403 error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it!

Click on the app in question, then choose 'Setup' then 'Advanced settings' and it is in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just transfer it to another Google Play Developer account.

Follow this tutorial post to do that: [Android Apps Transfer to Different Developer Account](https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/android-apps-transfer-to-different-developer-account-cd94e84893f7)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I'm not looking to transfer an app. I just need to change the status back to 'published'

Comment: Oh, I understood. I highly recommend you write to Google Play Support. They should help you with that issue.